# play on the computer

Tags: prepositions, collocation

Does 'play on the computer' sound natural? For example, in a sentence like "Kids play on the computer too much these days ignoring other ways of having fun".

I know that I can just say 'computer games' or 'video games', but I'm interested in that word combination precisely.

Comment: It's not a particularly strange expression.

Comment: If you say "play on the computer" it could include playing music, playing movies, etc.  If you want to refer only to games, say so.

Comment: It's an idiomatic usage. I'm not sure of the metaphor it uses. But surely the same one as in 'It was on television last night.' Perhaps via 'the TV's on' (vs off).

Answer (score 1):

It's about as natural as saying, "Kids are playing in the field" or "Kids are playing on the road"

It is completely normal unless your intention is to convey the idea of kids playing videogames, in which case you should probably specify that